# HDRI and Image in Background only in one color

Tags: hdri

I want to put a HDRI Image in background of my scene, and in this project the HDRI and Images will be shown only in 1 color. Creating a new blender file and adding the HDRI works fine. Only in this project not. I'm wondering if somebody knows why. Thanks a lot[image]

Comment: First: a .jpg image is not HDRi. And then, is the Low Dynamic Range Image in an equirectangular mapping?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, the problem was the orthographic view.